# Android Studio Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: debugging, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to start my first Android Studio app and coming across the same error over and over when I try to run or debug. I'm building a music app using the Spotify API and have imported the zipped jar files in the correct directory (under libs in my app).

What seems to be the problem is that maybe my SDK folder is in another drive? I don't think so, but it was the only thing I can think it would be. I even moved over my Android Studio folder and tried running it from the same D: drive but didn't make any difference.

I also have all the appropriate SDKs installed incl. SDK Tools, Platform-tools, SDK Build-tools 19.1, 20, API 19, 20, Android Support Repository, Library, Google Play serivces, Repository, USB Driver, and Intel Emulator.

This is the error I am getting:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702(2)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\Jesse\AndroidStudioProjects\SubRosa\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug C:\Users\Jesse\AndroidStudioProjects\SubRosa\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug C:\Users\Jesse\AndroidStudioProjects\SubRosa\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug C:\Users\Jesse\AndroidStudioProjects\SubRosa\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.spotify.sdk\spotifysdk\1.0.0-beta5\libs\jnihelpers-1.0.jar D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702(2)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\19.0.1\support-v4-19.0.1.jar C:\Users\Jesse\AndroidStudioProjects\SubRosa\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.spotify.sdk\spotifysdk\1.0.0-beta5\classes.jar C:\Users\Jesse\AndroidStudioProjects\SubRosa\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\19.0.1\classes.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    'D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Here is some my code and gradle builds/props:

local.properties

```
sdk.dir=D\:\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702(2)\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\\sdk
```

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0' // Note: this version should match the latest build-tools version
    // that you installed in the SDK manager

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jesse.spalding.subrosa"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotifysdk:1.0.0-beta5@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
}
```

If anyone has any idea what the deal is what this, please let me know. I need to start working on this for a final project and just can't figure this technical thing out for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your SDK is in a path that has a parenthesis in it (D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702(2)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk), which is causing problems in one of the phases of the build process. Move your SDK to a path with a simpler name and update its location in Android Studio (Project Structure > SDK Location) and you should be good to go.

Comment: That would do it! Thank you. I never would have guessed the (2) would have messed up the directory.

Comment: I don't have parenthsis in my path. `/Users/umer/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk`, still I am getting execution failed :app:dexDebug. How can I solve it?

Comment: Check if your project dir path has some strange signs in it. For example I had 'ä' in my dir. This generated similar error.